# The index work good even though the images are shown randomly

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this element in my html:

```
<img src="images/P-509-MyEgy 1.jpg" alt="Slide show" />
```

and my javascript code looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var imagesArray = ['images/P-509-MyEgy 2.jpg', 'images/P-509-MyEgy 3.jpg', 'images/P-509-MyEgy 4.jpg', 'images/P-509-MyEgy 1.jpg'];
    var imagesIndex = 0;    
    function slideShow() {
        $('img').fadeOut(750, function(){
            $(this).attr('src', imagesArray[imagesIndex]).fadeIn(750);
        });
        imagesIndex++;
        if(imagesIndex >= imagesArray.length){
            imagesIndex = 0;
        }
        //alert(imagesIndex);
    } 
    setInterval(slideShow,1000);
});
```

the commented alert return's what it seems to be right(1/2/3/then 0/1/2/3and so)

Comment: Is that space in the images name causing issues?

Answer (score 0):

The browser takes time to load the images before displaying them. You could preload them into an 1x1 div with opacity set to 0 to make sure they come out of the cache. The script is inside a .ready function so it will start when the images are done loading.